# Finalizer Thread 'Stuck' - Memory Problems

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, thread-safety

I have two threads:

1. Keep-Alive-SocketCleaner

```
Keep-Alive-SocketCleaner
Stack Trace is:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- waiting to lock <6401c483> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync) owned by "Finalizer" t@3
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:935)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.skip(BufferedInputStream.java:380)
- locked <2dbbb9aa> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.skip(MeteredStream.java:152)
- locked <46de4de6> (a sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream)
at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStreamCleaner.run(KeepAliveStreamCleaner.java:133)
- locked <46de4de6> (a sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- None
```

2. Finalizer:

```
Stack Trace is:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <3392bb6a> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:188)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- locked <6401c483> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
```

I can see the thread dump analyzer saying:

Finalizer Thread 'Stuck' - Memory Problems :  If finalizer thread is BLOCKED or WAITING for a prolonged period, it can result in OutOfMemoryError.

My application is giving OutOfMemoryError errors. But I am not sure why one thread is blocked due to another, and how come finalized is waiting for another thread.

It was working fine till today.

Comment: What Java version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finalizer thread isn’t stuck. The finalizer thread is waiting on a `ReferenceQueue` for finalizable objects, which is pretty normal as most of the time, there are no finalizable objects.

What’s unusual, is that the finalizer thread is reported to hold the lock `6401c483` despite not executing a `finalize()` method. The most plausible reason would be that a previously executed `finalize()` method acquired the lock but didn’t release it.

When I [search for “deadlock SSL” in the bug list](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6569529?jql=text%20%7E%20%22%5C%22deadlock%5C%22%20%5C%22SSL%5C%22%22) I find multiple entries. It’s worth noting that finalization will be removed completely and to my knowledge, the JDK implementation classes have been adapted already, not to use finalization, so this source of problems should be eliminated in up-to-date Java versions.